# iPad as a second monitor using computer's wifi-hotspot

Tags: wireless-networking, vnc, hotspot

I am on Ubuntu 18.04.

I have previously used my iPad as a second monitor using VNC when 
my devices were connected to the same network.

However, currently I can only use a LAN cable with my PC. I can connect my iPad to internet via
PC's WiFi-Hotspot, but VNC app doesn't recognize my computer this way.

Since both devices have internet I think it should be possible to build a work around to this?
 Any suggestions are welcome. Please help.

(A USB connection would be great too.)

Comment: Crossposted to AskUbuntu (https://askubuntu.com/questions/1217600/ipad-as-a-second-monitor-using-computers-wifi-hotspot)